# What does mvn gwt:run in the "backstage"?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have a maven gwt project and until now I've started it by using the Windows cmd with "mvn gwt:run". Now I want to configure it to Intellij but I don't understand how to do it because I don't understand what's happen in "backstage" when I run the command above. Sorry if the question it's a little bit unclear.

Comment: You can use the same maven goal with IntelliJ. Would that be a solution?

Comment: That will solve the running part but unfortunately not the problem of debugging

Comment: WIthout knowing which GWT and IntelliJ version you are using, it is hard to help. Try SuperDevMode and debug in the browser.